# Subviews for a UIViewController are not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, frame

I am attempting to create a UI programmatically. My problem is the view controllers subviews are not showing.

[image]

Here is how I am trying to create the UI:

`.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol TimerCreatorDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)timerCreatorControllerDismissedWithString:(NSString *)timerName andTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)timeInterval;
@end

@interface TimerCreatorController : UIViewController {

//    id timerCreatorDelegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<TimerCreatorDelegate> timerCreatorDelegate;

@property (weak, nonatomic) UIDatePicker *timerLength;
@property (weak, nonatomic) UITextField *timerNameTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) UIButton *createTimerButton;

//@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *timerLength;
//@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *timerNameTextField;

- (IBAction)createTimer:(id)sender;

@end
```

`.m`

```
#import "TimerCreatorController.h"

@interface TimerCreatorController ()

@end

@implementation TimerCreatorController

@synthesize timerCreatorDelegate;
@synthesize timerNameTextField;
@synthesize timerLength;
@synthesize createTimerButton;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    timerNameTextField.placeholder = @"This timer is for:";

    timerLength.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer;

    [createTimerButton setTitle:@"Start Timer" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [createTimerButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:46/255 green:134/255 blue:53/255 alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    createTimerButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:20];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    printf("viewWillLayoutSubviews Called.\n\n");
    [self.view addSubview:timerLength];
    [self.view addSubview:timerNameTextField];
    [self.view addSubview:createTimerButton];

    timerLength.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    timerNameTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    createTimerButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

    timerLength.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 216);
    timerNameTextField.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width - 300) / 2, timerLength.frame.size.height + 40, 300, 30);
    createTimerButton.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width - 96) / 2, timerNameTextField.frame.origin.y - 40, 96, 36);

    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                             [timerLength.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.topAnchor],
                                             [timerLength.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leftAnchor],
                                             [timerLength.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.rightAnchor],
                                             [timerLength.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.centerXAnchor],

                                             [timerNameTextField.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:timerLength.bottomAnchor],
                                             [timerNameTextField.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.rightAnchor constant:-37],
                                             [timerNameTextField.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leftAnchor constant:37],
//                                             [timerNameTextField.heightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute constant:30],

                                             [createTimerButton.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.centerXAnchor],
//                                             [createTimerButton.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute constant:96],
//                                             [createTimerButton.heightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute constant:36],
                                             [createTimerButton.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:timerNameTextField.bottomAnchor]
#warning Finish Layout Constraints
                                             , nil]];
    NSString *timerLengthString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(timerLength.frame)];
    NSString *timerNameTextFieldString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(timerNameTextField.frame)];
    NSString *createTimerButtonString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(createTimerButton.frame)];

    printf("timerLength: %s \n", [timerLengthString UTF8String]);
    printf("timerNameTextFieldString: %s \n", [timerNameTextFieldString UTF8String]);
    printf("createTimerButtonString: %s \n", [createTimerButtonString UTF8String]);
}

- (IBAction)createTimer:(id)sender {
    if ([self.timerCreatorDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(timerCreatorControllerDismissedWithString:andTimeInterval:)]) {

        [self.timerCreatorDelegate timerCreatorControllerDismissedWithString:timerNameTextField.text andTimeInterval:timerLength.countDownDuration];
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];
}
@end
```

Despite me setting the frames of my views,  the prints are showing frames of `{{0,0},{0,0}}`.

Comment: Where do you create the subviews?  I see you trying to use them, but not where you are actually creating the objects you are using.  Is it a .Nib file or are you actually doing everything programmatically?  And why are your subviews `weak` references?  If they are not help by anything else they will be released after they are created...

Comment: @Putz1103, that solved my problem. I am trying to just create them programmatically. Your comment made me realize, I forgot to initialize! PEBKAC. I Changed the references to strong, also. I would say post the answer.

Comment: Why in heaven's name would you create everything programmatically? It is a lot more work, doesn't give you a lot of features like container views, table view templates, etc, etc, etc, and is much harder to maintain than Storyboard/Nib based UI design. About the only reason I can see doing it this way is as a learning exercise. If I was a hiring manager interviewing somebody for a job and they said they did all their UI through code my reply would be "Next!"

Comment: @DuncanC That's foolish. I've written entire apps with no nib files. If I was the hiring manager's boss it would be the hiring manager who was fired. None of the "features" you listed does anything you can't do in code.

Comment: @DuncanC That's a gross oversimplification and I feel bad that you would discount a possibly amazing coder just because he didn't conform to your beliefs...  There are several reasons to use programmatic UI and there are several for GUI created UI.  I personally hate storyboard/nib/xib, but for things like table components and often repeated/simple UI they definitely have their place.  But this is a case of "To each their own."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you create the subviews? I see you trying to use them, but not where you are actually creating the objects you are using. Is it a .Nib file or are you actually doing everything programmatically? And why are your subviews weak references? If they are not held by anything else they will be released after they are created...

In Swift it will crash when you try to use an object before it is initialized.  Objective-C is a little more forgiving and will just do nothing if you tell it to use a nil object (at least in the instances you are using).